# Is the term "fresh and original" redundant?

Tags: phrases, expressions, adjectives, redundancy

I see this phrase all over the place.

[Fresh](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/original) in this usage appears to be in the usage:

> not previously known or used; new or different.

And directly lists original as a synonym.

And [original](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/original) in the usage:

> present or existing from the beginning; first or earliest.

or

> created directly and personally by a particular artist; not a copy or imitation.

All definitions from the Oxford online dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not wrong, but "redundant" may be overstating in. Near synonyms perhaps.

It is one of those double adjective structures so beloved of marketing people like *new and improved*. They want the rhythm of the phrase rather than the meaning.

Etymologically, both words are French, where they are almost never used together in the way they are here. Fresh comes from *fraîche* meaning cool, as in low temperature, and original comes from *original* / *originel* meaning original / primordial. Obviously usage trumps etymology but I always do a double take when I hear 'fresh coffee'.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit but not really.  They could both be used in the same sentence to describe something.  *Fresh* slang usually referring something new or modern or in-style.  *Original* could be conveying that it is different.  Both words have multiple meanings and there is overlap but not everywhere.

Comment: I would like to add to @RyeɃreḁd's answer. In the IT industry *fresh* refers to things that have a new feel to it, while *original* refers to things that are innovative. Example, when the iPhone first came out it was 'Fresh and Original'. Original concept (smart phone touch screen) and it was Fresh because of its design. The next version, iPhone 2, was 'fresh' for its slightly different design, but not original as far as the concept went. Where it made up for it was in its upgraded Operating System, which was original. So on and so forth.